# Use closures in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a JS function:

```
function test(restart){
  ...
}
```

which will be called like that:

```
test(); //returns 10
test(); //returns 15
test(); //returns 20;
test(true); //returns 10;
test(); //returns 15
test(); //returns 20
```

How can I achieve the above? I do not want to add code outside of the function's body. How to use closures correctly in that special case?

Comment: Please [include your attempt to solve this yourself](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). It will help answerers judge if you need just a little coaching, or that they need to explain more.

Comment: You can create a variable without `var` keyord

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because functions in JavaScript are objects, you could avoid creating a closure by assigning a property to the function:

```
function test(restart) {
  if (!test.value || restart) {
    test.value = 10;
  } else {
    test.value += 5;
  }
  return test.value;
};
```

```js
function test(restart) {
  if (!test.value || restart) {
    test.value = 10;
  } else {
    test.value += 5;
  }
  return test.value;
};

console.log(test()) //returns 10
console.log(test()); //returns 15
console.log(test()); //returns 20;
console.log(test(true)); //returns 10;
console.log(test()); //returns 15
console.log(test()); //returns 20
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take a closure over the start value and take a conditional statement  for either reseting the value or for incrementing the value.

```js
var test = (v => restart => v = restart ? 10 : v + 5)(5);

console.log(test());     // 10
console.log(test());     // 15
console.log(test());     // 20
console.log(test(true)); // 10
console.log(test());     // 15
console.log(test());     // 20
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let test = (restart) => {
  let v = 5;
  return (restart) => {
    if(restart){
      return v = 10;
    }else{
      return v += 5; 
    }
  }
}

let executeTest = test(); 
console.log(executeTest()); //10
console.log(executeTest()); //15
console.log(executeTest()); //20
console.log(executeTest(true)); //10
console.log(executeTest()); //15
console.log(executeTest()); //20
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly standard way to create a closure, albeit one which is more verbose than the elegant solution of Nina Scholz:

```
function countMaker(start = 10, step = 5){
    let count = start - step;
    function test(restart = false){
        if(restart){
            count = start
        } else {
            count += step;
        }
        return count;
     }
     return test;
}

const test = countMaker();
console.log(test()); //10
console.log(test()); //15
console.log(test(true)); //10
console.log(test()); //15
console.log(test()); //20
```

The parent scope of the inner function `test()` is the scope of `countMaker()`. This scope is the context in which `test` lives, and is what you mean by a closure. The state between calls to `test()` is maintained in this enclosing scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't put some code around a function, then you might use global namespace (window/global):

```js
function test(restart = false) {
  // replace window with global for Node.JS
  if(!window.myCounter)
  {
    window.myCounter = 10
  }

  if (restart) {
    window.myCounter = 10
  } else {
    window.myCounter+=5
  }
  
  console.log(window.myCounter)
}

test(); //returns 10
test(); //returns 15
test(); //returns 20;
test(true); //returns 10;
test(); //returns 15
test(); //returns 20
```

Comment: Without global variables please!

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper state has to be kept somewhere. In your question you seem to not want to use a closure. In this you seem to not want to use global state. Where do you want the state to live?

Comment: No, no. I do want the closure.

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper but a closure is when the function *is* contained in another function, and the most straightforward way to interpret " I do not want to add code outside of the function's body." is that you don't want it to be defined inside of another, enclosing, function.

Comment: @JohnColeman I think that OP doesn't fully understand what is a closure, but I also think that Nina Sholz has solved what had been asked with a closure (maybe in a totally different way that OP imagined).